# hazelcast WAN replication vs Solace

Tags: replication, hazelcast, solace, wan

We are evaluating IMDG technologies, Apache Geode vs Hazelcast, any real differences?

hazelcast has WAN replication. Also hazelcast can be used with Solace.

whats the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazelcast supports different implementations for WAN replication through its `WanPublisher` and `WanConsumer` interfaces.

By default Hazelcast uses `WanBatchReplication` implementation which creates TCP connections to target members and send the WAN events in batches. This implementation also has in-memory (replicated) queues to send events asynchronously and to deal with differences of WAN link throughput.

You can replace this implementation with `SolaceWanPublisher` which publishes WAN events to Solace queues and doesn't use the direct TCP link approach used by `WanBatchReplication`. 
Replication of WAN events are provided by Solace and target members consumes events from that queues.
So source and target members are unaware of each others network topology.

You may want to check [Hazelcast Documentation](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.2/manual/html-single/index.html#hazelcast-wan-replication-with-solace) or [this](https://hazelcast.com/resources/hazelcast-wan-replication-solace/) white paper for details.

Comment: Thanks, Could you please let us know exact differences with Gemfire/Geode with Hazelcast?

Comment: For me, the most important difference is Geode and Gemfire's source may not always be in sync and may have different versions. (Described [here](https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/115000400208-GemFire-vs-Geode-FAQ) so a bug-fix might be available for Gemfire but not for Geode for a while. Hazelcast and Hazelcast Enterprise always released simultaneously. Beyond that it depends on your requirements but I'd suggest checking both of their benchmarks and feature comparison charts.

Comment: Sure. Thank you, feature comparison charts are either biased or not keep up to the current versions. I will update this thread once I found anything related.